# What property returns the regular expression when re.compile is called?

Tags: python, regex

```
def foo ():
   x = re.compile('^abc')

   foo2(x)

def foo2(x):
```

How do I get x to return `'^abc'`? within the following code

```
logging.info('x is ' + x.???)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pattern](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/re-objects.html)