# Getting the pattern back from a compiled re?

Tags: python, regex

Assume I have created a compiled re:

```
x = re.compile('^\d+$')
```

Is there a way to extract the pattern string (^\d+$) back from the x?

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189861/what-property-returns-the-regular-expression-used-when-recompile-was-called
(although this one is stated more nicely)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i obtain pattern string from compiled regexp pattern in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415924/how-can-i-obtain-pattern-string-from-compiled-regexp-pattern-in-python) - while this Q here was earlier, the later one has answers with more info, including Py3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What property returns the regular expression used when re.compile was called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189861/what-property-returns-the-regular-expression-used-when-re-compile-was-called)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get it back with

```
x.pattern
```

from the Python [documentation on Regular Expression Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.pattern)

Comment: bill, do you know why dir(x) does not show pattern in the list?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It could be because it's not a method, but a property.

Comment: I'll post another question :)

Comment: Good idea, now I'm interested to know.  :)

Comment: I actually rephrased it a bit, since the docs say that the list need not to be complete (whatever Guido means by this statement...). check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191010/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-objects-methods-and-attributes