# How to get a complete list of object's methods and attributes?

Tags: python

```
dir(re.compile(pattern))
```

does not return pattern as one of the lists's elements. Namely it returns:

```
['__copy__', '__deepcopy__', 'findall', 'finditer', 'match', 'scanner', 'search', 'split', 'sub', 'subn']
```

According to the manual, it is supposed to contain

> the object's attributes' names, the
>   names of its class's attributes, and
>   recursively of the attributes of its
>   class's base classes.

It says also that

> The list is not necessarily complete.

Is there a way to get the **complete** list? I always assumed that dir returns a complete list but apparently it does not...

Also: is there a way to list only attributes? Or only methods?

*Edit: this is actually a bug in python -> supposedly it is fixed in the 3.0 branch (and perhaps also in 2.6)*

Comment: using `dir()` or the inspect module is generally the right way to do it.

Did you use `re` module just as an example or do you want to achieve a special goal?

Comment: Are you sure that the pattern is actually kept as data once compiled? I was under the impression that the point of compiling a pattern was to produce the finite state automata necessary to parse the given pattern.

Comment: @hop cannot dir be sidestepped by classes? For example, they can make their on `__dir__()`

Comment: ytpillai: correct, but only in Python 3. Even so, the question is, whether such a class would fall under the "general case"

Answer (score 149, accepted):

For the **complete** list of attributes, the short answer is: no. The problem is that the attributes are actually defined as the arguments accepted by the `getattr` built-in function. As the user can reimplement `__getattr__`, suddenly allowing any kind of attribute, there is no possible generic way to generate that list. The `dir` function returns the keys in the `__dict__` attribute, i.e. all the attributes accessible if the `__getattr__` method is not reimplemented.

For the second question, it does not really make sense. Actually, methods are callable attributes, nothing more. You could though filter callable attributes, and, using the `inspect` module determine the class methods, methods or functions.

Comment: inpect.getmembers(re.compile(pattern)) does not yield pattern as a member either, so it probably uses dir internally... This sucks!

Comment: I could also use callable to check if they are methods, but that is not the point... The point is I cannot trust dir to return even the list of attributes that are actually publicly visible...

Comment: inspect is meant to be "at least as" trustworthy as dir().

on the other hand, re is a very complicated module

Comment: What do you define by "publicly visible" ? If you mean "can be accessed", then that is a lost cause for the reason given. Otherwise, 'dir' always return the list of attributes accessible with the default implementation of getattr.

Comment: Well, take a look at the other answer. There is some notion of public visibility in ppython, hence the __dir__ in order for the objects to control what is returned. Still, I came across this cause I use dir in the interactive shell like *all the time* :D. Anyway, thans.

Comment: dir(my_class) returns something different than my_class.__dict__.keys(). the former also outputs the methods of the class like __init__ and __doc__

Comment: What about `help()`? :P

Answer (score 61):

That is why the new `__dir__()` method has been added in python 2.6

see:

- http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#other-language-changes (scroll down a little bit)
- http://bugs.python.org/issue1591665

Comment: I get this error: >> __dir__(pyrenderdoc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__dir__' is not defined

Comment: `__dir`__() is a method on object, not a function - please read the links in the answer and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__)

Comment: One-liner to pprint all attributes and their values: `pprint({k:getattr(ojb,k) for k in obj.__dir__()})`

Answer (score 22):

Here is a practical addition to the answers of PierreBdR and Moe:

- For Python >= 2.6 and *new-style classes*, `dir()` seems to be enough.
- For *old-style classes*, we can at least do what a [standard module](http://docs.python.org/library/rlcompleter.html) does to support tab completion: in addition to `dir()`, look for `__class__`, and then to go for its `__bases__`:

  ```py
  # code borrowed from the rlcompleter module
  # tested under Python 2.6 ( sys.version = '2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) \n[GCC 4.4.3]' )

  # or: from rlcompleter import get_class_members
  def get_class_members(klass):
      ret = dir(klass)
      if hasattr(klass,'__bases__'):
          for base in klass.__bases__:
              ret = ret + get_class_members(base)
      return ret


  def uniq( seq ): 
      """ the 'set()' way ( use dict when there's no set ) """
      return list(set(seq))


  def get_object_attrs( obj ):
      # code borrowed from the rlcompleter module ( see the code for Completer::attr_matches() )
      ret = dir( obj )
      ## if "__builtins__" in ret:
      ##    ret.remove("__builtins__")

      if hasattr( obj, '__class__'):
          ret.append('__class__')
          ret.extend( get_class_members(obj.__class__) )

          ret = uniq( ret )

      return ret
  ```

(Test code and output are deleted for brevity, but basically for new-style objects we seem to have the same results for `get_object_attrs()` as for `dir()`, and for old-style classes the main addition to the `dir()` output seem to be the `__class__` attribute.)

Answer (score 11):

Only to supplement:

1. `dir()` is the **most** powerful/fundamental tool. (**Most recommended**)
2. Solutions other than `dir()` merely provide **their way** of dealing **the output of `dir()`**.

   Listing 2nd level attributes or not, it is important to do the sifting by yourself, because sometimes you may want to sift out internal vars with leading underscores `__`, but sometimes you may well need the `__doc__` doc-string.
3. `__dir__()` and `dir()` returns identical content.
4. `__dict__` and `dir()` are different. `__dict__` returns incomplete content.
5. **IMPORTANT**: `__dir__()` can be sometimes overwritten with a function, value or type, by the author for whatever purpose.

   Here is an example:

   ```
   \\...\\torchfun.py in traverse(self, mod, search_attributes)
   445             if prefix in traversed_mod_names:
   446                 continue
   447             names = dir(m)
   448             for name in names:
   449                 obj = getattr(m,name)
   ```

   **TypeError: descriptor `__dir__` of `'object'` object needs an argument**

   The author of PyTorch modified the `__dir__()` method to something that requires an argument. This modification makes `dir()` fail.
6. If you want a **reliable** scheme to traverse all attributes of an object, do remember that every pythonic standard **can be overridden and may not hold**, and every convention may be unreliable.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it, useful for simple custom objects to which you keep adding attributes:

Given an object created with `obj = type("Obj",(object,),{})`, or by simply:

```
class Obj: pass
obj = Obj()
```

Add some attributes:

```
obj.name = 'gary'
obj.age = 32
```

then, to obtain a dictionary with only the custom attributes:

```
{key: value for key, value in obj.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith("__")}

# {'name': 'gary', 'age': 32}
```

Comment: list of all attributes in Python 3.x: {key: value for key, value in obj.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith("__")}['_declared_fields'].keys()