# Getting all public variables and methods in SWIG

Tags: python, swig, public-method

If my C++ class has been wrapped by SWIG and exposed to the python interpreter. Is there a way to retrieve a collection of all public variables and methods in python? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not SWIG-related, so it might not solve your specific problem, but you might want to look at Python's `dir` and `__dir__` functions. There's a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/191010/445210).