# How to obtain all fields of an object?

Tags: python

*Disclaimer*: I'm doing my first steps in python that's why the question may sound a little silly.

How to list all variables which are stored in `self`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/191010/776084.

Answer (score 5):

You might want `inspect.getmembers` as it'll list members of objects even if those objects have `__slots__` defined as those objects do not have a `__dict__`.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class F:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.x = 2
... 
>>> inspect.getmembers(F())
[('__doc__', None), ('__init__', <bound method F.__init__ of <__main__.F instance at 0xb7527fec>>), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('x', 2)]
>>> class F:
...     __slots__ = ('x')
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.x = 2
... 
>>> inspect.getmembers(F())
[('__doc__', None), ('__init__', <bound method F.__init__ of <__main__.F instance at 0xb72d3b0c>>), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('__slots__', 'x'), ('x', 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Every python object has a special member called `__dict__` which is a dictionary containing all the instance's member.

`self.__dict__.keys()` lists their names

`self.__dict__['foo']` gives you access to the value of the member `foo`

BTW, basically, writing something like `self.foo = 1` is equivalent (at the basic level of things) to writing `self.__dict__['foo'] = 1` that works as well.

Comment: Be warned that this is an oversimplification. Objects can (and some do, for good reasons) overload attribute access, which makes `__dict__` either incomplete or entirely useless. More commonly, `property` is used to create "attributes" which are not in `__dict__` and silently call a function. There's also `__slots__`, which can remove `__dict__` completely. And I'm sure there are more exceptions.

Comment: @delnan true, but since he was asking about the very basic use case, this is a good approximation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a beginner, you're asking a simple question so here's a simple answer: You can see *all* contents of a class or object, not just the variables but also the methods and other content, with the command `dir`. It's great when you're poking around at the python prompt. Try

```
dir("hello")  # examine string object
dir(str)      # examine string class
import os     
dir(os)       # Examine module
```

And yes, from inside a class you can use it to examine `self`, since `self` is just a class object. You can use `dir`, `type` and `help` on the contents of a class to get more detail about them:
    dir(os.stdout)