# How to get actual list of names of object if custom __dir__ implemented?

Tags: python, internals

Official docs [says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called
>   and must return the list of attributes. This allows objects that
>   implement a custom `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()` function to
>   customize the way `dir()` reports their attributes.

If custom `__dir__` implemented, results, returning by another function, `inspect.getmembers()`, also affected.

For example:

```
class С(object):
    __slots__ = ['atr']
    def __dir__(self):
        return ['nothing']
    def method(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr = 'string'

c = C() 
print dir(f) #If we try this - well get ['nothing'] returned by custom __dir__()
print inspect.getmembers(f) #Here we get []
print f.__dict__ #And here - exception will be raised because of __slots__
```

How in this case list of names of object might be getted?

Comment: You keep changing the question... I was about to post that `dir()` basically just uses the object's `dict` (and some stuff from its type obj, apparently), you could use `__dict__`, but you just made that impossible. What is your goal here? Why are you using `__slots__`?

Comment: My goal is to understand how list of names can be getted in all possible situations. Thats why I focused question on exceptional cases. ps That is final edition :)

Comment: If you're using `__slots__`, the list of attributes isn't dynamic, so you know all the attributes already.

Comment: ... using `c.__slots__`. There are other ways to get the methods as well if you want those too. I'm not really sure what else to say since  I don't really know the use case for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "names"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer to original question- does `inspect.getmembers()` use `__dir__()` like `dir()` does?

Here's the source code for `inspect.getmembers()` so we can see what it's really doing:

```
def getmembers(object, predicate=None):
    """Return all members of an object as (name, value) pairs sorted by name.                                                                                                                                     
    Optionally, only return members that satisfy a given predicate."""
    results = []
    for key in dir(object):
        try:
            value = getattr(object, key)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        if not predicate or predicate(value):
            results.append((key, value))
    results.sort()
    return results
```

From this we see that it **is** using `dir()` and just filtering the results a bit.

#### How to get attributes with an overridden `__dir__()`?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191029/1460235), it isn't possible to always get a complete list of attributes, but we can still definitely get them in some cases/get enough to be useful.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

> If the object does not provide `__dir__()`, the function tries its best
>   to gather information from the object’s `__dict__` attribute, if
>   defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not
>   necessarily complete, and may be inaccurate when the object has a
>   custom `__getattr__()`.

So if you are not using `__slots__`, you could look at your object's `__dict__` (and it's type object's) to get basically the same info that `dir()` would normally give you. So, just like with `dir()`, you would have to use a more rigorous method to get metaclass methods.

If you are using `__slots__`, then getting class attributes is, in a way, a bit more simple. Yes, there's no dict, but there is `__slots__` itself, which contains the names of all of the attributes. For example, adding `print c.__slots__` to your example code yields `['atr']`. (Again, a more rigorous approach is needed to get the attributes of superclasses as well.)

#### How to get methods

You might need a different solution depending on the use case, but if you just want to find out the methods easily, you can simply use the builtin `help()`.

#### Modified PyPy `dir()`

Here's an alternative to some of the above: To get a version of `dir()` that ignores user-defined `__dir__` methods, you could just take [PyPy's implementation](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/0f2f6fcca4d3/pypy/module/__builtin__/app_inspect.py?at=default#cl-27) of `dir()` and delete the parts that reference `__dir__` methods.

Comment: @GillBates You can just use `help()`. (I edited that into my answer.)

Comment: Getting methods strictly from code with help() - thats interesting. Thank you for detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew pointed out in the other answer, `getmembers` apparently returns the subset of `dir` results that are actual attributes.

```
>>> class C:
>>>   def foo(self):
>>>     pass
>>>   def __dir__(self):
>>>     return ['test']
>>>
>>> import inspect
>>> c = C()
>>> dir(c)
['test']
>>> inspect.getmembers(c)
[]
```