# List class methods in order of declaration

Tags: python

In Python how to get list of class methods as they declared?
inspect.getmembers and dir return alphabetic ordered list, but I need a list of methods in exact declaration order.

Comment: Possible duplication of [How to get a complete list of object's methods and attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191010/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-objects-methods-and-attributes)

Comment: @Whispered That is in no way a duplicate.

Comment: It depends if the `__prepare__` method has been used to change the class's underyling storage from a `dict` to an `OrderedDict` or similar -- Otherwise, that's why test suites and such stick with a naming convention that can be sorted into a specific order by name etc.... Otherwise, you can't really do what you're asking if the object wasn't set up to be able to support it...