# Where is this protocol defined?

Tags: python, protocols

Say we do:

```
class thing(object):
    pass
```

and then I do `>>> thing.__eq__`, then I get `<method-wrapper '__eq__' of type object at 0x0E8B68D0>`. But if we do `'__eq__' in dir(thing)`, I get an `NameError` exception saying that `__eq__` is not defined, but if its not defined, then how did I get a method wrapper return, clearly its defined, but if dir can't see it, where is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir(thing)` returns a *list* of method names, all strings. Test with the actual string:

```
'__eq__' in dir(thing)
```

This will still return `False` as `dir()` only lists a summary of the most important methods. You'd have to additionally list everything on the metaclass of `thing` as well, which in this case is `type`:

```
>>> '__eq__' in dir(type(thing))
True
```

Quoting from the documentation of [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

> **Note**: Because `dir()` is supplied **primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt**, it tries to supply an interesting
>   set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently
>   defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across
>   releases. For example, **`metaclass` attributes are not in the result
>   list** when the argument is a class.

Emphasis mine.

`__eq__` is the fallback implementation here; `type()` defines a reasonable default (falling back to an identity test, `==` implemented as `is`) and as long as your custom class doesn't implement a custom version, *that is not interesting* and listing it would only needlessly clutter the result of `dir()`.

Comment: So how can I get a list of all the methods?

Answer (score 1):

`dir` does not list all attributes:

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) say:

> The resulting list is not necessarily complete...
>   The default dir() mechanism behaves differently with different types
>   of objects, as it attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than
>   complete, information...
>
> Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an
>   interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names
>   more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set
>   of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For
>   example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the
>   argument is a class.

---

Also, I assume that you tested `'__eq__' in dir(thing)` -- note the quotation marks -- since `dir` returns a list of strings.

---

[ジョージ shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313703/190597) a way to list all attributes based on code from the rlcompleter module:

```
import rlcompleter

def get_object_attrs(obj):
    """
    based on code from the rlcompleter module
    See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313703/190597 (ジョージ)
    """
    ret = dir(obj)
    ## if "__builtins__" in ret:
    ##    ret.remove("__builtins__")
    if hasattr(obj, '__class__'):
        ret.append('__class__')
        ret.extend(rlcompleter.get_class_members(obj.__class__))
        ret = list(set(ret))
    return ret

class Thing(object):
    pass

print(get_object_attrs(Thing))
```

prints

```
['__module__', '__format__', '__itemsize__', '__str__', '__reduce__', '__weakrefoffset__', '__dict__', '__sizeof__', '__weakref__', '__lt__', '__init__', '__setattr__', '__reduce_ex__', '__subclasses__', '__new__', '__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__mro__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__dictoffset__', '__call__', '__doc__', '__ne__', '__getattribute__', '__instancecheck__', '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasshook__', '__gt__', '__name__', '__eq__', 'mro', '__basicsize__', '__flags__', '__delattr__', '__le__', '__repr__', '__hash__', '__ge__']
```

From which we can obtain a list of attributes in `Thing` not listed by `dir`:

```
>>> print(set(get_object_attrs(Thing)) - set(dir(Thing)))

set(['__ne__', '__abstractmethods__', '__subclasses__', '__eq__', '__instancecheck__', '__base__', '__flags__', '__mro__', '__le__', '__basicsize__', '__bases__', '__dictoffset__', '__weakrefoffset__', '__call__', '__name__', '__lt__', '__subclasscheck__', '__gt__', '__itemsize__', '__ge__', 'mro'])
```

`get_class_members(cls)` collects attributes from `cls` *and all the bases of `cls`*.

Thus, to get a more complete list of attributes, you must add to `dir` the attributes of the object's class, and all the attributes of the object's class's bases.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is how Python 2 handle `__eq__`.
Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588776/how-is-eq-handled-in-python-and-in-what-order) for further information.

In python 3, things have changed ([no more `__cmp__` method](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons)) and `'__eq__'` **is** in the list of method names returned by `dir(thing)`.