# How to list all fields of a class (and no methods)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, introspection

Suppose `o` is a Python object, and I want all of the fields of `o`, without any methods or `__stuff__`. How can this be done?

I've tried things like:

```
[f for f in dir(o) if not callable(f)]

[f for f in dir(o) if not inspect.ismethod(f)]
```

but these return the same as `dir(o)`, presumably because `dir` gives a list of strings. Also, things like `__class__` would be returned here, even if I get this to work.

Comment: I've been noodling with [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) but can't get it 100% right, but that module might help?

Comment: I've looked at inspect also ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python dictionary from an object's fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields)

Comment: have you tried the built in `vars` function or the field `.__dict__` for your object?

Comment: @CharlieParker tough to say. The specific memory fades after 8.5 years.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can get it via the `__dict__` attribute, or the [built-in `vars`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) function, which is just a shortcut:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     foobar = 42
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.foo = 'baz'
...         self.bar = 3
...     def method(self, arg):
...         return True
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__dict__
{'foo': 'baz', 'bar': 3}
>>> vars(a)
{'foo': 'baz', 'bar': 3}
```

There's only attributes of the object. Methods and class attributes aren't present.

Comment: This is per-instance.

Comment: This is probably the best approximation you're going to get, but it should be noted that this considers callable instance attributes (which are sometimes used and are effectively like methods) as non-methods and considers class attributes with no corresponding instance attribute not a field (even though it acts like one for most purposes). It also ignores properties and fails on classes with `__slots__`, which may or may not matter.

Comment: also doesn't work if __dict __ is not defined.  which it isn't always.

Comment: __slots__ doesn't always contain everything you're looking for either.

Answer (score 21):

You could use the built-in method `vars()`

Comment: I'm in favor of calling other methods instead of mangled magic methods and properties in Python. I think this is much more Pythonic way. So, take my +1.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

Comment: @JohnSohn hard to figure out the issue from just the error message but it is telling us that whatever is passed to `vars()` doesn't have a `__dict__` attribute indicating that what's passed probably isn't an `object`. And indeed with `a = "text"; vars(a)` we get a similar message.

Answer (score 15):

The basic answer is "you can't do so reliably".  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191010/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-objects-methods-and-attributes).

You can get an approximation with `[attr for attr in dir(obj) if attr[:2] + attr[-2:] != '____' and not callable(getattr(obj,attr))]`.

However, you shouldn't rely on this, [because](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

> Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases.

In other words, there is no canonical way to get a list of "all of an object's attributes" (or "all of an object's methods").

If you're doing some kind of dynamic programming that requires you to iterate over unknwon fields of an object, the only reliable way to do it is to implement your own way of keeping track of those fields.  For instance, you could use an attribute naming convention, or a special "fields" object, or, most simply, a dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you can create your own members surrounded by double underscores, this'll break.

Comment: @2rs2ts: Yes, that is true.  There is no way around that.  There's no way to programatically tell if a double-underscore name is "magic" or not; you have to read the documentation.

Comment: These are naming conventions, you shouldn't create your own members by surrounding them with double underscores.

Comment: @Benjamin: Indeed. At the end of the [**Descriptive: Naming Styles**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) section of [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), regarding names with both double-underscore-prefix & suffixes, it says "Never invent such names; only use them as documented."

Comment: I'm starting to find myself in agreement with this.

Answer (score 9):

This should work for callables:

```
[f for f in dir(o) if not callable(getattr(o,f))]
```

You could get rid of the rest with:

```
[f for f in dir(o) if not callable(getattr(o,f)) and not f.startswith('__')]
```

Comment: Almost. I got `['__dict__', '__doc__', '__module__', '__weakref__', 'a', 'b']` with a dummy class with `a` and `b` as class members.

Comment: Close, but still includes `__dict__`, `__doc__`, etc.

Comment: I'd add this.[f for f in dir(m) if not callable(getattr(m,f)) and not f.startswith('__')]

Comment: Note that `__dict__` is a better option if you want to preserve the order of the fields.

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate through an instance's `__dict__` attribute and look for non-method things.
For example:

```
CALLABLES = types.FunctionType, types.MethodType
for key, value in A().__dict__.items():
    if not isinstance(value, CALLABLES):
        print(key)
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
```

You can do it in a single statement with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
print([key for key, value in A.__dict__.items() if not isinstance(value, CALLABLES)])
```

Which would print `['foo', 'bar']`.

Comment: There's no need to filter out methods, since they're in the class `__dict__`, not the instance `__dict__`s.

Comment: @Blckknght: I put the test in because a class is an object, too. However, I realized after your comment the need to check for than one type of callable, and have modified my answer. Thanks. If one can assume that the object is a new-style class instance, then what you said is true and the `for` loops could be simplified.

Answer (score -3):

You can get it via *fields* attribute: `o._fields_`