# How to get a dict from scrapy item?

Tags: python, dictionary, scrapy

I need the values in a dict. But item uses some abstraction on top of it. How to get the fields in a dict from an item ?

I know [scrapy allows dict to be returned in place of item](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1064) now. But I already am using item in my code, so how to convert it.

Comment: Have a look at 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945067/how-list-all-fields-of-an-class-in-python-and-no-methods][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945067/how-list-all-fields-of-an-class-in-python-and-no-methods

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me like :

```
class Product(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()


i = Product(name='foo)
print dict(i)
```

gets you a dictionary {'name': 'foo'}

```
vars(p)
p.__dict__
```

gets you: 
{'_values': {'name': 'foo'}}

If you don't want to create a new dictionary, just grab the _values key from the above:

```
vars(p)['_values']
p.__dict__['_values']
```

Comment: any reason not to use `p.__dict__['_values']`

Comment: No, I just figured you only needed one example. I will add for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works great but it won't work when you have nested items. In such case you might want to first convert the item to string and then to json like so:

```
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, scrapy.Item):
            return dict(o)
```