# Class[_] equivalent in python

Tags: python-3.x, scala

I want to perform the following scala code into python3 language

```
    class xyz{  
      def abc():Unit={  
        val clazz:Class[_] = this.getClass()
        var fields: List[String] = getFields(clazz);
        val method = clazz.getDeclaredMethods()
        val methodname=method.getName()
        val supper= clazz.getSuperclass()
        println(clazz)
        println(fields)
        println(method)
}}
```

Comment: Well, `abc()` is an infinite loop without side-effects and `mno()` prints `"hello"`. Are you sure this is the code you want to translate?

Comment: method name and class name is random just for reference ......main part,of which I want conversion is written in abc()....I am kind of new for python language and why abc() is infinite loop

Comment: because clazz will never be null

Comment: gotcha........what's the conversion then ??

Comment: `abc()` in its current form is just `while True: pass` with extra steps. I am almost certain this is not what you want.

Comment: I have edited the post.....whatever task is performed here I just want to perform it in python..........equivalent for getClass(), for getFields() etc

Answer (score 3):

> Class[_] equivalent in python

`Class[_]` is a static type. Python doesn't have static types, so there is no equivalent to the static type `Class[_]` in Python.

> I want to perform the following scala code into python3 language
>
> ```scala
> class xyz{  
>  def abc():Unit={  
>    val clazz:Class[_] = this.getClass()
>    var fields: List[String] = getFields(clazz);
>    val method = clazz.getDeclaredMethods()
>    val methodname=method.getName()
>    val supper= clazz.getSuperclass();}
>  def mno():Unit={
>    println("hello")}}
> ```

`abc` is simply a NO-OP(*). `mno` just prints to `stdout`. So, the equivalent in Python is

```py
class xyz:
  def abc(self):
    pass

  def mno(self):
    print("hello")
```

Note that I made `abc` and `mno` instance methods, even though it makes no sense. (But that's the same for the Scala version.)

---

(*) Some who knows more about corner cases and side-effects of Java Reflection can correct me here. Maybe, this triggers some kind of Classloader refresh or something like that?

Comment: please see the post again .........I have done some editing. whatever value is returned by the methods used like getClass(), getFields() etc ......I want same kind of value using python

Answer (score 2):

You can't get one-to-one correspondence simply because Python classes are organized very differently from JVM classes.

1. The equivalent of `getClass()` is [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type);
2. there is no equivalent to `Class#getFields` because fields aren't necessarily defined on a class in Python, but see [How to list all fields of a class (and no methods)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945067/how-to-list-all-fields-of-a-class-and-no-methods).
3. Similarly `getSuperclass()`; Python classes can have more than one superclass, so [`__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes) returns a tuple of base classes instead of just one.

Comment: Also, there is no equivalent to `getDeclaredMethods` because methods are actually just (well, not quite, but close enough) functions assigned to fields (see #2). And there is no equivalent to `getName` because methods (functions) don't have names, they are simply objects assigned to variables / fields (see #2 again).