# Python-requests: Where to find all possible attributes?

Tags: python, attributes, python-requests

I was using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) in conjunction with a lambda function (correct me if you call it something else) to GET a url. Given that the url varied according to the value of `epoch()`, I wanted to print it for debugging.

Lucky for me, `print(kiwi.url)` works, because `kiwi.url` exists, but for future reference, how can I find all possible attributes for python-requests, or even other modules, without relying on luck?

```
import time, requests
epoch = lambda: int(time.time()*1000)
kiwi = s.get('http://www.example.com/api?do=%i' % epoch())
print(kiwi.url) #I found the .url attribute by chance.
           ^
```

Comment: Have you tried [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/191029/3001761

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally speaking you can introspect Python objects with the [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) and [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars) functions:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar')
>>> dir(response)
['__attrs__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_content', '_content_consumed', 'apparent_encoding', 'close', 'connection', 'content', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 'encoding', 'headers', 'history', 'is_permanent_redirect', 'is_redirect', 'iter_content', 'iter_lines', 'json', 'links', 'ok', 'raise_for_status', 'raw', 'reason', 'request', 'status_code', 'text', 'url']
>>> 'url' in dir(response)
True
>>> vars(response).keys()
['cookies', '_content', 'headers', 'url', 'status_code', '_content_consumed', 'encoding', 'request', 'connection', 'elapsed', 'raw', 'reason', 'history']
```

You could also just use the [`help()` function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help) and Python will format the docstrings on a class; `response.url` doesn't have a docstring but *is* listed in the attributes section.

For `requests` specifically, just check out the excellent [API documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/). The `url` attribute is listed as part of the [`Response` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#classes).

Answer (score 2):

Use `dir()` in the shell:

```
>>> import requests
>>> req = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
>>> dir(req)
['__attrs__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__',
'__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__',
'__iter__', '__module__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__',
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_content', '_content_consumed',
'apparent_encoding', 'close', 'connection', 'content', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 
'encoding', 'headers', 'history', 'is_redirect', 'iter_content', 'iter_lines',
'json', 'links', 'ok', 'raise_for_status', 'raw', 'reason', 'request',
'status_code', 'text', 'url']
```