# How can I obtain pattern string from compiled regexp pattern in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have some code like this one:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('my pattern')
>>> print p
_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x02274380
```

Is it possible to get string `"my pattern"` from `p` variable?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
p.pattern
```

Read more about re module here:
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't read docs becouse i try i dir(p) and it display only several attributes and methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415924/how-can-i-obtain-pattern-string-from-compiled-regexp-pattern-in-python/1415943#1415943

Comment: I did the same, assumed there was no simple way to get it :)

Comment: seems like in python3 dir(some_compiled_pattern) displays the attributes,  but not in 2.7

Comment: >Why not to read docs before posting such questions?
Because when you google StackOverflow returns first. Perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 22):

From the ["Regular Expression Objects"](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects) section of the `re` module documentation:

> `RegexObject.pattern`
>
> The pattern string from which the RE object was compiled.

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('my pattern')
>>> p
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x1001ba818>
>>> p.pattern
'my pattern'
```

With the `re` module in Python 3.0 and above, you can find this by doing a simple `dir(p)`:

```
>>> print(dir(p))
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__doc__',
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__',
'__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__',
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'findall', 'finditer', 'flags',
'groupindex', 'groups', 'match', 'pattern', 'scanner', 'search',
'split', 'sub', 'subn']
```

This however does *not* work on Python 2.6 (or 2.5) - the `dir` command isn't perfect, so it's always worth checking the docs!

```
>>> print dir(p)
['__copy__', '__deepcopy__', 'findall', 'finditer', 'match', 'scanner',
'search', 'split', 'sub', 'subn']
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes:

```
print p.pattern
```

hint, use the `dir` function in python to obtain a list of members:

```
dir(p)
```

this lists:

```
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__',
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__',
'__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
'__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
'findall', 'finditer', 'flags', 'groupindex', 'groups', 'match', 'pattern',
'scanner', 'search', 'split', 'sub', 'subn']
```

Comment: `help( value )` is much more useful on the console.